# Как изменить целевой элемент JS-кода?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Как из приложенного кода сделать, чтобы действие применялось для button вместо чекбокса?
Если это возможно, можно ли сделать его универсальным, без привязки к тегу,например, только к классу?

```js
//плавный скролл при выборе поломки вниз
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 
(() => {
  const handler = evt => {
    if (evt.target.checked)
      tabs.scrollIntoView({ block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth' });
  };
  const tabs = document.querySelector('#content');
  for (let cbox of document.querySelectorAll('.linkinp'))
    cbox.addEventListener('change', handler);
})();

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="linkinp"><br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br><br>
<div id="content">Ку-ку</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. убрать условие if так как checked не бывает на клик кнопки
2. В цикле слушать не change а клик

Должно получится прилизительно так:

```
(() => {
  const tabs = document.querySelector('#content');

  const handler = () => {
    tabs.scrollIntoView({ block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth' });
  };

  for (let cbox of document.querySelectorAll('.linkinp')) {
    cbox.addEventListener('click', handler);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Александр, а как сделать, чтобы код работал на все упомянутые классы?

Answer (score 1):

так ?

```js
let linkinp = document.querySelector('.linkinp');

linkinp.addEventListener('click', function(e){
 if( e.target.getAttribute('class') == 'linkinp' ){
  content.scrollIntoView({ block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth' });
 }
})
```

```html
<button class="linkinp">asdad</button>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br>
Контент<br><br>
<div id="content">Ку-ку</div>
```

Comment: Мой код работают на все элементы на сайте с классом .linkinp. Тоесть при нажатии на любой такой элемент, сайт проскролится к элементу с айди - #content

Comment: @AlexandrVyshnyvetskyi пытаюсь указать вместо id класс, но тогда ничего не работает. Извините за некомпетентность.

Comment: @QuickBrownFox вам нужно скроллить страницу к другому элементу не к элементу с id #content а к другому у которого другой класс? Можете показать html и обьяснить по нажатию на что нужно что бы скролило и куда скролило?

Comment: Да, верно.
А можно ссылку на сайт вам скинуть,там немного специфическая ситуация, чтобы уместить в код?

Comment: @AlexandrVyshnyvetskyi https://codepen.io/MorrisJerrald/pen/mddjeLE

Comment: @AlexandrVyshnyvetskyi все никак не могу адекватно вычленить всю взаимосвязь в виде краткого кода. Если Вам будет понятнее на сайте, то вот ссылка. Спасибо! http://apple-service.srv160751.hoster-test.ru/